# Convergence to $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I just wanted to know why 
\begin{equation}
(-2\varepsilon \varphi(0) + o(\varepsilon)) \ln \varepsilon
\end{equation}
goes to $0$ as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. $\varphi(0)$ is just a constant in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because
$\lim_{x \to 0} x \ln x = 0$.

Setting $y = 1/x$,
this is the same as
$\lim_{y \to \infty} \dfrac{\ln y}{y}
=0
$
which can be proved in a number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see it clearer since the exponential is strictly increasing/decreasing function, you can make the substitution 
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\epsilon^{\alpha}\ln{\epsilon}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\exp{(-\alpha t)}t=0$$

wich is $0$ for $\alpha>0$